# Units in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ modulo a divisor $d|n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n\geq 1$ be an integer and let $d|n$ be a divisor. I want to prove the following statement:

> For any $1\leq k<d$ with $\gcd(k,d)=1$, there exists a number $1\leq u<n$ with $\gcd(u,n)=1$ such that $u=k$ mod $d$.

Can someone provide a proof or a reference?

Comment: In other words, the canonical map $U(n) \to U(d)$ is surjective. See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31495/when-does-a-ring-surjection-imply-a-surjection-of-the-group-of-units

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/885216/why-f-colon-mathbbz-n-times-to-mathbbz-m-times-is-surjective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $ $ We seek $u = k\!+\!jd\,$ with $\,\gcd(k\!+\!jd,n)=1.\,$ Such a $j$ exists by [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/647600/242) and $\,\gcd(k,d)=1$